# How do I investigate commands being run when changing directories?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, shell

I see “**awk**”, “**find**”, “**sed**”, and “**which**” momentarily appear in my Terminal window's title when changing directories.  *(And not all of these always appear and there could be some I'm missing; I imagine this is because the title changes multiple times before the UI redraws.)*

Although this is likely just some shell scripts and additions I've installed along the way (git status in PS1, perhaps), **I'd like to investigate it just to make sure**.  Is there an easy way to find out what script(s) are calling these?

***Note on Context:** I'm looking for a general investigative approach to discovering what is calling the sub-commands.  My programmer's mindset makes me want a solution that would temporarily replace the sub-command with a stubbed one *(à la `#define`/`#undef`)* that would dump a stack trace at the point of call, then either call the original command or just abort.  This approach may or may not be applicable to the shell.*

***Also:** I'm primarily on OS X 10.8 using GNU bash 3.2.48.  I'm not sure if the system and bash version is completely relevant to the problem at-hand— a solution that works on my Debian instance as well would be nice.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash you can use `set -o verbose`:

```
$ set -o verbose
update_terminal_cwd; 
$ cd ~/Documents
cd ~/Documents
update_terminal_cwd;
```

`bash -lv` would start a new login shell with the same option enabled.

For example `update_terminal_cwd` is defined in `/etc/bashrc`, which isn't indexed by Spotlight. But you can see the definition with `declare -f update_terminal_cwd` or `set`.

`sudo opensnoop -n bash` shows what files are accessed by processes named bash.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the command itself.
The problem is with the git status in PS1.
Simply, every time you supply a command, PS1 becomes evaluated.
In order for git status to appear, there is a batch of command executed in the current working directory.
For example, it checks if the current directory is a git repo or not, then checks the branch name, may be some commit number or what status you decided to keep.

I am not quite sure if the solution suggested by Lauri will show such evaluations or not, but you may give it a shot.

Comment: The git-status-in-PS1 thing was just a guess, because I know I have that set up.  While I know there probably are other things altering my PS1 (on my system), is PS1 the only thing that gets evaluated when changing directories?  Or are there other hooks I should investigate?

Comment: I will of course try disabling my PS1 settings and see if that solves my specific issue.  However, the general problem still stands.